# Normalization confusion , is a type of something a transitive dependency?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database-normalization

Does the v_type need to be in a separate table, yes or no please explain which normalization rule does is applied ? I want this table normalize upto 3NF.

```
Vechile
v_id (pk) | V_name     |  V_type
----------------------------------
v1          Ferrai        car
v2          merto         train
v3          City_bus      bus
v4          Lamborgini    car
v5          grey hound    bus
```

Comment: You need to define the candidate keys and dependencies. You have labelled v_id as PK but that isn't enough information to go on. It isn't clear what the determinant(s) of v_type would be.

Comment: so does that means v_type should be on separate table, here V1 determines the vehicle name (V_name) but i'm confuse does the v_name or V-id  determines the type. what assumption can you make.

Comment: You must decide what determines v_type based on your analysis and understanding of the business domain. You can't apply the principles of normalization unless you properly understand the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as stands here, this table is normalized. It's legal to use strings like "car" or "metro" as primary key for a V_type table, or just as attributes of your vehicle table. Normalization would only be violated if you put additional attributes of V_type entity into the Vehicle table, e.g. an attribute `public` that determines whether it's public or private transport.

Even if you don't have such additional attributes, there might be a reason for separating the vehicles types into a table of their own. That way you can control which vehicle types may exist. In your current design, if someone enters a record like

```
v18   Mercedes   cra
```

that would be accepted. If, however, you have a vehicle type table that contains entries only for valid vehicle types like car, metro, bus, and train, you can ensure by a foreign key constraint that the vehicle table will only reference those types.

Comment: I believe the potential violation of 3NF that @mhrzn is concerned about is v_name->v_type. On the information given we don't know whether that dependency should hold or not, we also don't know whether v_name is a key or not, therefore we don't know whether the Vehicle table satisfies 3NF.